# How to install rhq-agent from rhq-server using silent installation?

Tags: networking, jboss, rhq

Is it possible to install rhq-agent from rhq-server silently only by specifying agent IP Address.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux:

create the following script and call like script.sh &

This will run in background

pseudo-code

> ssh with Agent IP > /dev/null
>
> curl jar file from https://$rhq-server-ip-address:$port/agentupdate/download > /dev/null
>
> ssh root@$agent-ip "java -jar /path/to/rhq-enterprise-jar --install > /dev/null"

this will install the agent with no output.